# Hot Towel - Dynamic Dom element data bindings

Tags: jquery, html, knockout.js, hottowel

I've had an issue today with data-binds using knockout in Hot Towel API. Take the following for example...

```
var vm = {
    item: { entry: 'yes' }
}

return vm
```

and the html

```
<div data-bind="text: item.entry"></div>
```

This works, however when I modify the js to add the div dynamically

```
var vm = {
    canActivate: canActivate,
    activate: activate,
    attached: attached,
    item: { entry: 'yes' }
}

return vm

function canActivate(){
     return true;
}

function activate() {
     logger.log(title + ' View Activated', null, title, true);
     return true;
}

function attached() {
     $('#page').append('<div data-bind=\"item.entry\"></div>);
}
```

The data-bind fails. I've attempted use ko.cleanNode and then tried to rebind the DOM object but get a cannot reapply bindings message. Has anyone come up with a solution for dynamically added DOM data-binds?

Comment: May i ask why you want to append an element? You shouldn't really do much of that when using knockout. Instead you'd have a list of items and then have knockout render them for you using a foreach binding. And for adding a new one... then you'd simply add it to the viewmodel list and it'd all just work and render instantly.

Comment: That's currently what I'm looking at now, however its a big task in terms of what I'm doing as my page layout is database driven.

Answer (score 0):

You could use templates and the `ko.renderTemplate` method to achieve this ([see fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MtTr9/)).

**HTML**

```
<div id="page"></div>

<script type="text/html" id="appendedEntry">
    <div data-bind="text: entry"></div>
</script>
```

**JS**

```
var vm = {
    item: { entry: 'yes' },
    append: appendDiv
};

function appendDiv() {
    ko.renderTemplate('appendedEntry', vm.item, {}, document.getElementById('page'));    
}

ko.applyBindings(vm);

vm.append();
```

You can learn more about the `ko.renderTemplate` method (exactly what it does and it's parameters) in [this article](http://aboutcode.net/2012/11/15/twitter-bootstrap-modals-and-knockoutjs.html).

Also, although I'm not sure if it will apply to your specific case, keep in mind that Durandal has [delayed binding handlers](http://durandaljs.com/documentation/Interacting-with-the-DOM.html) which allow your normal KO binding handlers to interact with DOM elements after the view composition is complete.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid manually rendering the element, you can do it like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/Akn5T/

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: items">
    <li>
        <span data-bind="text: entry"> </span>
    </li>
</ul>

<button data-bind="click: add">Add new</button>
```

---

```
function vm() {
    var items = ko.observableArray([
        { entry: 'yes' },
        { entry: 'no' },
        { entry: 'maybe' }
        ]);

    function add(){
        items.push({entry: "new"})
    }

    return {
        items: items,
        add: add
    }
};

ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

You basically want to represent your database in the viewmodel and then forget about rendering it manually by having the appropriate bindings in the view like above.